# How to contol camera aspect ratio in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a problem with the aspect ratio in unity 3d. 
I am developing a game and everything was edited and created in 16:9.
So I would like to fix it, because if I change to 4:3, the display gets cutted from left and right.

Therefore I am asking myself if there is any method or script to control the aspect ratio.

Comment: you mean like [`Camera.aspect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-aspect.html)?

Comment: I think so. My problem is that my display gets cutted when I switch to 4:3.

Comment: well yes that's what happens if you use 4:3 on a 16:9 display ... it is not that wide and something will be cut off left and right ... what would you like to happen instead?

Comment: Is there any way to avoid that so that I could see the same on both displays?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about your UI being cut off as well? Then you should set the anchors of the UI elements correctly.

Your 3D world will be inherently cut off left and right on a 4:3 display. Or would you expect the image to shrink and have black bars at the top and bottom?

Comment: I just don't want to lose some of the display after switching to 4:3. I want to avoid that cut.

Comment: So you want black bars on the top and bottom. I personally don't know any game that does that... Why is it so bad if the left and right are cut off? Anyway... in the player settings, there is a setting "Supported Aspect Ratios". Maybe it helps to only select 16:9 there.

Comment: I think I have read somewhere how to remove the black bars. It is bad for two reasons: 1) In the menu I lose a lot of buttons 2)In the game process there is a lot of are lost

Comment: A screenshot would really help. As for the buttons, you should really just correctly set the anchors so they know how to handle screen resizes.

Comment: On the Button's RectTransform component, there are a few shortcuts on the top left. If you need to fine-tune the anchors, set the x and y values for the min and max anchors. For example, if the button should stay at the bottom right, both anchors should be at (0, 1), I think.

Comment: Thx. Unfortunately the player settings did not help. It still does cut the display when I select 4:3.